# Magento 2 adminhtml getUrl not working as expected

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, controllers, router

I want to make a post request to a backend custom controller, which does not work

My controller resides in

Namespace/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/Discount/Index.php

```
<?php namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Discount;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $discountAmount = $this->getRequest()->getParam('discountAmount');

        die("now");
    }

}
```

My routes.xml in Namespace/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="adminhtml" frontName="adminhtml">
            <module name="Namespace_ModuleName" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

In my block I'm calling the url by `<?php echo $this->getUrl('adminhtml/discount/index'); ?>`

This does not seem to create the correct url anyway,because when I try to use this url, it simply redirects to the dashboard

Comment: Have your file inside index folder, Namespace/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/Discount/Index/Index.php or inside Discount folder?

Comment: sorry for confusion, its Namespace/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/Discount/Index.php

Answer (score 1):

When in the adminhtml scope, there is no need to use 'adminhtml/' in the `getUrl()` method.

The correct to fetch the URL should be: `<?php echo $this->getUrl('discount/index'); ?>`